# Many Q's downvoted and closed?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I recently visited [WorkPlace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) for the first time.

On the front page, it looks like most questions have multiple downvotes, and many questions are closed.

I'm all for downvoting and closing bad questions (and hopefully leaving constructive feedback at the same time), but this seems out of control!

Is this the work of a few disgruntled down-voters? or is the level of snark on the Workplace.SE just out of control?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your last paragraph.  Do you really see downvotes and closures as an indication of snark, or have I misunderstood?  (If you see snark in the form of rude comments, please flag them.)

Comment: To me, large-scale downvoting, especially without comment or obvious cause, is either a small number of angry people, or a herd-mentality of cliquish, "snarky" people.   I'm open to other interpretations.  (I just counted, and on the front page, fully 20 of 40 questions shown are closed for one reason or another. 16 questions have Negative scores.  Other sites do not seem to have nearly these ratios)

Comment: Are any of those 16 questions undeserving of their downvotes? If yes, you can achieve a lot more by explaining why you think these questions are good questions for the site, instead of this vague rant.

Comment: Related:http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1627/437

Answer (score 6):

Workplace SE, like many other SE sites, focuses on specific goals. Specifically, questions should be about a real problem faced in the workplace and should be something we can answer factually without guesswork.

Looking at a few down voted questions on the main page, they can be improved via editing by focusing on the quality of the communications.  If you feel a question has hidden value, edit it to make sure it is well written, using good spelling and grammar.

You can also leave comments to ask the askers clarifying questions that will help unearth enough detail to make the questions more answerable with facts and references. While not a guarantee, this may help get the questions upvoted and reopened.

Comment: I think the improve-and-reopen cycle is also taking a little longer just at the moment because many users are busy with other seasonal concerns.

Comment: I wonder how many of recent troublesome questions are simply dumped at us by [Kofia hat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245658/165773) hunters: "first post on a specific Stack Exchange site, which has to take place in those days..."

Comment: @gnat: Ha! That's funny. But the answer to your question is 'No. Not a chance.'

Comment: @JimG. I don't understand you

Comment: @Gnat: Kofu hats have nothing to do with it. You're thinking too hard.

Comment: @JimG. I still don't understand. I referred and quoted hat description, have you read it? "first post on a specific Stack Exchange site, which has to take place in those days..."

Comment: I actually have people down vote me just because of my name.

Comment: Because a lot of workplace questions are "Opinion based" and the community hasn't quite decided where the dividing line is yet between relevant questions and those which are "**Primarily** opinion based".