# "Collapse" on-hold, duplicate and closed questions?

Tags: feature-request

This problem has been discussed before here ([High volume of questions being put On Hold or Closed - is that a problem?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2038/3192)) and again here ([Many Q's downvoted and closed?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/many-qs-downvoted-and-closed?cb=1)), so I won't go into that discussion again.

I was wondering if we could "collapse" these questions, with the user having the option of expanding them. This is similar to how

[image: Without expansion]

expands to the following on clicking the triangle.

[image: After expansion]

In this case, right below the ALL QUESTIONS title, we could have an option "See On Hold/Duplicate/Closed Questions", which when clicked on would show such questions.

I have been on SE for long enough to realise that this should be posted on meta.SE, but I thought of posting it here first because other sites may not recognise this as a significant problem.